# Get data passed when loading view

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm handling a site built with Codeigniter and wondering how (and if possible) to access the data which is passed on as an argument when loading a view from a controller script.

```
$this->load->view ('view_to_open', $data);
```

$data is an array handled in the controller script in where the view is loaded from and I could use some of that information in the view. Trying to simply accessing the array in the view results in nothing..

Is there any way I can access/load that data and use it in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this example helps to understand a bit your issue

**Controller**

```
$data['example'] = 'Hello World!'; 
$this->load->view ('view_to_open', $data);
```

**View**

```
<div>
<?php echo $example; ?>
</div>
```

Will output this:

```
Hello World!
```

If you need more information visit the 2.2 [Views](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) guide or 3.0 [Views](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html), depending on the version you are actually using

Answer (score 2):

Sure this is possible. Try it like this:

```
$data['content'] = array(); //yourarrayhere
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

Inside the view you just access the data with `$content`, **not** `$data['content']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.this will help you

In Controller

```
$data['content'] = array(); // put your array of data here.
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

In View page

```
<?php 
foreach($content as $row)
{
   echo $row->id;//what field you want to display.access like this
}

?>
```